# If $x^2 + ax + b =0$ has an integer solution then show that it divides $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x^2 + ax + b =0$ has integer solution then show that it divides $b$

Now $$x = \frac {-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$$
Since $x$ has integer solution so $2$ must divide numerator. So $a =2k$ and $\sqrt{a^2 - 4b}=2m$. How do i proceed?

Comment: Write it like: $(x-n_1)(x-n_2) = x^2 +ax+ b$.

Comment: Actually, you cannot say that $a=2k$ and $\sqrt{a^2-4b}=2m$ because it is only the sum that is even (you may have $-a=3$ and $\sqrt{a^2-4b}=1$

Comment: Do the assumptions include that $a,b$ are integers?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger It is not given in the question, but i think yes

Comment: Then the answer show the was. Otherwise the assertion would be false. Consider, for example, the polynomial  $(x-\frac12)(x-2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it has integer solution $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then we have

$$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$$

That is $$x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x + \alpha\beta = 0$$

That is $\alpha \beta = b$

Comment: So since  let $\alpha$ is integer. SO $\beta$ divides $b$

Comment: The hypothesis is that the equation has one integer solution, not that both are integers. Of course it's easy to check that if one solution is an integer then so is the other, but it needs to be done.

Comment: ah, i see, i misunderstood the question then. If $a$ and $b$ are integers, and $\alpha$ is an integer, then $\alpha + \beta=-a$ would imply that $\beta$ is an integer.

Comment: We don't need to show whether other root is integer or not, don't we?. Check my first comment

Comment: we say a number $\beta$ divides $b$, if we can find an integer $k$ such that $\beta k = b$, here $k$ is $\alpha$ which is an integer.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what i have written?

Comment: hmm... the question says show that "it" divides $b$. Does "it" refers to $\alpha$ or $\beta$?

Comment: It refers to alpha.  but it can be shown by showing beta to be integer

Comment: yup, then just show that $\beta$ is an integer, then use it to conclude that $\alpha$ divides $b$.

Answer (score 2):

$$b=-x(x+a)$$ so that both $x$ and $x+a$ divide $b$.

Answer (score 0):

The question (when $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$) and its proof are a special case of a more general result.

*Let $p=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1 x+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$ with **integer** coefficients. Then $p(u)=0$ and $u\in\mathbb{Z}$ implies that $u$ is a divisor of $a_0$.*

The proof immediately follows from the fact that $u$ divides $a_l u^l$ for all $l\geq 1$.